# Problema com logout em sistema laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

Tenho um admin em que já esta a fazer login correctamente, tenho na função fazer logout feita mas esta a dar o seguinte erro: quando faço logout diz que não existe a coluna `remember_token` na minha tabela.

Como posso resolver isto? Pois eu criei as tabelas personalizadas.

**Controller**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use DB;
use Auth;
use Redirect;
use Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function showLogin ()
    {
        if (Auth::check()){
            return Redirect::to('/admin');
        }
        return view('admin/login');
    } 

    public function postLogin()
    {
        $username = Input::get('username');
        $passwd   = Input::get('password');

        $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();

        if ($user && Hash::check($passwd, $user->passwd)) {
            Auth::login($user);
            return Redirect::intended('admin');    
        }

        return Redirect::back()->with('error_message', 'Dados Incorrectos')->withInput();
    }

    public function logOut()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return Redirect::to('admin/login')->with('error_message', 'Logged out correctly');
    }
}
```

Comment: Tentou criar esse atributo `remember_token` na sua tabela?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando crias a tuas migrações adiciona uma coluna a essa tabela:

```
...
$table->rememberToken();
...
```

Também podes fazer manualmente adicionando a coluna `remember_token` com o valor default `NULL` na tua tabela:

```
ALTER TABLE admins ADD COLUMN remember_token VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: E importante esse campo ?

Comment: É para que o "laravel" saiba que é uma tabela "com sistema de autenticação" @CésarSousa

Comment: ok entendi e resolveu acrescentando esse campo tento uma resposta como a outra resolve o problema mas vou por certa a sua que foi a primeira a ser dada

Comment: @CésarSousa ambas estão certas, a minha apenas dá uma maneira "manual" de fazer isso, por incrivel que pareça há muita gente que não faz migrações assim pois já recebe o SQL pronto

Comment: @Miguel as `migrations` facilitam tanto pra fazer versionamento e na hora de desenvolver rsrs.

Comment: Claro que sim, eu faço-as sempre que posso, mas não afastes a hipotese que estares a migrar uma app inteira para laravel, aí recebes o SQL e todo o conteudo da Base de Dados @FelipePaetzold

Comment: @Miguel bom nesse caso é mais complicado, porém geralmente pego aplicações do zero então felizmente não tenho esse problema ^^

Comment: @FelipePaetzold, nem é assim tão complicado basta pores criares a BD e pores o SQL que recebes a correr, depois "só" tens de fazer os models e respetivas relações, escusas é de estar a criar as migrations

Comment: Já vi utilizarem `liquibase` (semelhante as migrations) para migrar um banco de dados `mysql` para  `oracle`, montaram no `liquibase` a estrutura exata e geraram o banco, foi lindo de ver

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece por que você está usando uma tabela que não é padrão do `Laravel 5.3`, segue a `migration` de criação para a tabela.

> Caso queira criar a tabela do zero.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('NOME DA SUA TABELA', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

---

> Caso queira editar a tabela existente.

```
public function up()
        {
            Schema::table('NOME DA SUA TABELA', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->rememberToken();
            });
        }
```